# Analyze audio input from microphone Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am planning to create a music visualizer on a website. There are objects that should change in size, and shape based off of the current music that is playing (a non-classical, multi-line song probably, such as Don't Stop believing). I want to at least be able to know the volume of the music and if possible, any pitches that can be picked up (is FFT possible in Javascript?). Are there Sound API's out there that that will let me do this in Javascript, or at least online?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is possible with the Web Audio API.  Check out the Audio Input demo on http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/.  You don't need to perform the FFT yourself - the web audio api will do it for you.